# Words with friends on facebook messenger

Tags: words-with-friends

In the past week, when playing words with friends, I've encountered  a glitch. I play all my tiles, but the game doesn't end. It allows my opponent to make a play. When my turn comes to play, I have nothing, my options are to resign or pass.   What is wrong? Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Not 100% sure, its been a while since I played this game, but I think this might be by design. Does your opponent still have tiles to play? If they still have words to play, I think the game will let them keep playing them and force you to pass. Could be wrong, like I said, its been years since I played it.